# i tried installing tensorflow using 'pip install tensorflow ' in anaconda prompt and command prompt. its showing following output

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: If you're using anaconda, have you tried running `conda install tensorflow`?

Comment: @IzaakWeiss That worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below commands mentioned, it worked for me

```
conda update wrapt
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** First try to install wrapt manually using following command

```
pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

> make sure that you use "--ignore-installed" flag when install 'wrapt' as above mentioned command

**(2)** Then install tensorflow with pip

eg:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to upgrade numpy with following incase its not compatible otherwise it will throw errors.

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while installing from conda environment. **Always upgrade conda or pip before a new installation**.

Following worked for me:

- [Optional] If installing in conda environment, then temporarily remove the conda env:

  `conda remove --name myenv --all`
- Update all conda packages:

  `conda update --all`
- Create conda env again:

  `conda create -n myenv`
- Activate conda env:

  `conda activate`
- Install tensorflow:

  `pip install tensorflow`