# Jupyter Notebook doesn't show any output in vpython and shows output only once after restarting the kernel and not again

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vpython

Hi I was using vpython in jupyter notebook to get a graph visual and run this code:

```
from vpython import *
    
Plot = gdots(color = color.black)
for x in arange(-5,5,0.1):
    Plot.plot(pos =(x,cos(x)))
```

I get the output first but when I try to change the function like add sin instead of cos I don't get any errors nor do I get any output. It also happens when I try to run it again. No output.
Although, the problem is solved when the kernel is restarted but then only once does it show any output.
After that, no output whatsoever.

Before running this code. I installed vpython in anaconda but first it failed as it wouldn't uninstall one of elements and would show an error message in the command prompt saying
 `"Cannot uninstall 'terminado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."`

After this I found the solution by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705686/i-tried-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-install-tensorflow-in-anaconda-prompt) post.

and I ran a similar code like this:

```
pip install terminado --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

I rerun `pip install vpython` and then it ran and it got completed in command prompt

But as soon as I run the first code in jupyter notebook a windows firewall message pops up and is requesting me to allow access for Private and public networks coming from python under the path anaconda.exe. I tick for both and let them allow access. And this problem still occurs. How to get out of this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just re-start the kernel and you will see the figure

Comment: you could add some details about how to restart the kernel, or which kernel